# Minor rewording needed on "Privileges - access review queues"

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The "[Access review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)" page currently says the following:

> The First Posts queue contains the first few posts asked by new users, who may not fully understand the best way to ask questions or what's on- and off-topic on this site.

The wording implies that the First Posts queue only includes questions. However, in practice it sometimes includes answers as well (albeit less frequently).

I'd suggest rewording it to something like this:

> The First Posts queue contains the first few posts by new users, who may not fully understand the best way to ask/answer questions or what's on- and off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, why not. The page has been updated.